# How can I store a word from the response of server in a variable?

Tags: asp.net

I am getting a response from server.  and I want to store that word "Accepted" in a variable.
Response is

> Request Status : Accepted,Time:0(s)

Comment: Its a string or any else format? - @jittu

Comment: string[] spaces1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(responseFromServer.Trim(), " ");
                                                                string st = spaces1[1].Trim(); I am  using this but the variable store the first word.

Comment: Can I write it as. string[] spaces1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split("Request Status : Accepted,Time:0(s)", " ");
 string st = spaces1(1).Trim();

Comment: No its not working still its storing first word request in st.